# How to send a word file in automated email from odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11

Would like to know if there is a way to send a file that is not in ir.attachment through automated emails.
My xml declaration at the moment:

```
<record id="transfer_template" model="mail.template">
    <field name="name">Transfer Notification</field>
    <field name="email_from">${ctx.get('email_from')|safe}</field>
    <field name="subject">Transfer Notification</field>
    <field name="email_to">${ctx.get('email_to')|safe}</field>
    <field name="lang">${object.lang}</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_employee_history"/>
    <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
    <field name="body_html" type="html">
            <div style="padding:0px;width:600px;margin:auto;background: #FFFFFF repeat top /100%;color:#777777">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                       style="width:600px ;text-align:justify; margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; background:inherit; color:inherit">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:0px 10px 5px 5px;font-size: 14px;">
                                <p>Hello,</p>
                                <p>Test</p>
                                <p>Goodbye!</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </field>
</record>
```

Comment: So how did you have to get that file ?

Comment: You need to define your path of custom file there.

Comment: lets say i can put a path to my file... how to declare it here or what code should i write